# MySQL is converting MyISAM tables to INNODB automatically

Tags: centos5, mysql5

I recently upgraded MySQL server on CentOS 5 with MySQL 5.0.96
After upgrade when i am trying to import old database dump which has got both MyISAM and INNODB tables in a single database, MySQL is converting all MyISAM table to INNODB.

Am not sure why this is happening. But i certainly dont want this to happen.

Any clue why this could be happening?

Comment: `/etc/my.cnf`? `/var/log/mysqld.log`?

Comment: Is MyISAM enabled? You can check by running SHOW ENGINES

Comment: Yes the MyISAM is enabled. I have checked it. Rather MyISAM is Default engine when i issue command SHOW ENGINES...

Comment: Are you sure your database dump didn't specify the tables be created with InnoDB?

Comment: Of course am doing this day in and day out for past 3years without a trouble

Answer (score 0):

If your dumps don't specify which engine to use for each table then the system default will be used. I suspect your system default is InnoDB.

Comment: mysqldump --opt -K --triggers -c -n -R is the command i use to create mysql dump. This does not include any options to define database table type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..well i could resolve this issue by deleting the file ib_logfile1 in /var/log/mysql and restarting mysql service.

I guess this was from the older version and was causing a problem to start the innodb engine.